# InDesign: how to disable text frame from snapping to blue grid inside it?

Tags: adobe-indesign, text, snapping

Below is a snapshot showing the problematic text frame. When I resize the text frame, it snaps to the blue grid inside it. That means it goes one block at a time, rather than smoothly.

How can I turn this blue grid off, so I can fine tune the text frame size?

[image: text frame that has the resizing problem]

Comment: Are you saying the text frame is snapping to the text inside the frame? Or do you have a text frame over the blue grid? If you want to fine tune the text box, you could turn off "Smart Guides" under "View - Grids & Guides".

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the text inside your text frame have *Align to baseline grid* turned on.

Disable it by selecting the text and clicking *Do not align to baseline grid* in the *Paragraph* panel.

[image]

Comment: Why would _Align to Baseline Grid_ affect what the text frame snaps to when it’s resized?

Comment: OK, maybe I misunderstand. Just guessing to provoke some more info.  Do *you* understand the question?

Comment: As far as I can tell, the asker has a text frame with some sort of blue grid-like thing inside it (though I don’t recognise what exactly that is – doesn’t look like a normal InDesign grid), and whenever they try to resize the text frame, its bounding lines somehow snap to that grid (even though it’s _inside_ the frame), so it will only resize in jumps equivalent to one grid line, not smoothly and precisely. _How_ this can come to be, I have no idea, and I’m suspicious of that blue ‘grid’ as well, but that’s how I understand the question.

Comment: But couldn't the "blue grid" inside the text frame be anchored objects? And then what if the paragraph style snapped to baseline grid *and* the text frame was set to auto size?